# how to get FormGroup from FormControlName?

Tags: angular

I have a custom error prompt directive in Angular which prompts the error if the filed is invalid during submit automatically without adding separate error HTML element. I added this directive in all the field percent inside a 'form' element. now the problem is that if there is two 'form' available in one component, the error is coming for another form element which I did't submit the form. so I want to know how can I check 'FormControlName' from which form it comes from.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, OnInit, InjectionToken, Inject, Input, Optional, Host, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef, HostBinding, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { merge, Observable, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { MainService } from 'src/app/services/main/main.service';
import { ErrorpromptComponent } from 'src/app/components/errorprompt/errorprompt.component';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appFormErrorMsg]',
    providers: [NgModel]
})

export class FormErrorMsgDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    ref: ComponentRef<ErrorpromptComponent>;
    container: ViewContainerRef;
    formSubmitSubscriptionRef: any;
    errors = {
        required: (error) => 'This field is required',
        minlength: ({ requiredLength, actualLength }) => `Expect ${requiredLength} but got ${actualLength}`,
        patern: () => 'invalid name provided',
        email: () => 'Invalid email provided',
        min: () => 'Invalid Amount Entered',
        custome: () => 'Invalid data provided',
        date: () => 'Invalid Date'
    };
    constructor(
        private control: NgControl,
        private _main: MainService,
        private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
    }
    @Input() customErrors = {};
    @HostBinding('class.invalid') isElementInvalid = false;
    @HostListener('input') onInputChange() {
        console.log('input changes');
        if (this.ref) {
            this.clearError();
        }
    }
    @HostListener('ngModelChange') onNgmodelInputChange() {
        console.log('input changes');
        if (this.ref) {
            this.clearError();
        }
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.formSubmitSubscriptionRef = merge(this._main.formSubmitObservable).pipe().subscribe((value) => {
            console.log(value);
            console.log('submit observable', value, this.control);
            const controllErrors = this.control.errors;
            this.clearError();
            console.log('Errors ->', controllErrors, this.control);
            if (controllErrors) {
                const firstKey = Object.keys(controllErrors)[0];
                const getError = this.errors[firstKey];
                const text = this.customErrors[firstKey] || getError(controllErrors[firstKey]);
                console.error({ firstKey, getError, text });
                this.showError(text);
            }
        });

    }
    showError(errorTxt) {
        this.isElementInvalid = true;
        if (!this.ref) {
            console.log('element ref', this.ref);
            const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ErrorpromptComponent);
            this.ref = this.vcr.createComponent(factory);
        }
        this.ref.instance.text = errorTxt;
    }
    clearError() {
        if (this.ref) {
            this.ref.instance.text = '';
        }
        this.isElementInvalid = false;
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.formSubmitSubscriptionRef.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can inject ElementRef and access to the attributes of the input tag, but not the formControlName itself

If you want to acces the FormGroup, inject `@Optional() @Host() NgForm`

```
constructor(private el:ElementRef,
            private control: NgControl,
            @Optional() @Host() private form:FormGroupDirective,
            ...){}

//to get an attribute
console.log(this.el.nativeElement.getAttribute('name'))
//to get the form, e.g.
console.log(this.form.form.value)
console.log(this.control.control.parent.value)
console.log(this.control.control.parent==this.form.form) //true
```

Comment: form is coming undefined for me, how to pass form in directive?

Comment: ::glups:: you can use `this.control.control.parent` or inject `FormGroupDirective`to access the parent of the control. I just corrected in code

Comment: thanks, @Eliseo, i was looking for this  'this.control.control.parent' . it worked for me and please upvote my question

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen

- if attribute type is not set for button as buttons inside a form become a type="submit" by default.
- when there are two buttons with type="submit" as they trigger (ngSubmit) by emitting an event

Try console logging both the forms, If Submitting one form is calling both the submit methods or not